# Difference between Gullstrand-Painlevé (GP) time coordinate and proper time $\tau$

Tags: general-relativity, time, coordinate-systems, free-fall

The [GP coordinates](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gullstrand%E2%80%93Painlev%C3%A9_coordinates) version of Sch. metric uses a new time coordinate, t', which is the time read from a free-falling clock that was dropped from rest at large r and falls past the event we're measuring as it occurs.

I accept that coordinate time, so t' in this case, and proper time, τ, are different and I follow the mathematics needed to calculate t'. But I can't seem to understand conceptually how they are two different times?

Please can somebody enlighten me?

Comment: See "https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gullstrand%E2%80%93Painlev%C3%A9_coordinates".

Comment: It's not exactly clear what you're asking here. The GP time coord *is* the proper time of a free-falling observer.

Comment: Some related questions, although they aren't specifically about Gullstrand-Painlevé: https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/470705/123208 & https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/53334/123208

Comment: From what I understand, any observer in the coordinate system that doesn't freefall right alongside that clock will have a proper time that differs from that of the clock due to differences in kinetic and/or gravitational time dilation, so its $\tau$ will differ from $t'$.

Answer (score 1):

I am not 100% clear about what you are asking, but proper time is the local time of a particular observer, whereas coordinate time is defined globally, so they cannot be the same. They should coincide at the position of the clock.